# warning: ignoring return value of 'int scanf(const char*, ...)', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

Tags: c++, c, time, compilation, scanf

I was solving a problem. The question goes like this: Jill & Jung love lucky numbers. The lucky numbers is obviously 4 & 7, if a decimal representation of positive numbers contains 4 & 7, the positive integer is considered lucky. For example `444`, `474` and `7` are lucky, where `4773` and `89` are not lucky.

Jill wanted to convert non-lucky integers to lucky integers, by discarding the non-lucky digits in an integer. For Example answer for number `767456` is `774`, answer for number `9974` is `74`, answer for `1775667` is `777`.

Jill will give you two numbers `a` and a lucky number `b`. Find an *minimum positive integer* `c` (`c > a`) that will contain a lucky integer 'b'.

Input Format:

Integer `t`: number of test cases. Follow two integers `a` and `b` (`1 <= a`, `b <= 100000`). `b` is always a lucky Integer.

Output Format:

print a minimum number `c` that contains the lucky number `b`

Sample Input

```
1
47 74
```

Sample Output

```
74
```

I am just a beginner in C. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int r1, r2, c1, c2, d1, d2, a, b, c, d, n, x, i, flag = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &r1, &r2, &c1, &c2, &d1, &d2);
        for (a = 0; a < 25; a++)
            for (b = 0; b < 25; b++)
                for (c = 0; c < 25; c++)
                    for (d = 0; d < 25; d++) {
                        if ((a + b == r1) && (c + d == r2) &&
                            (a + c == c1) && (b + d == c2) &&
                            (a + d == d1) && (c + b == d2) &&
                            a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0) {
                            printf("YES\n");
                            break;        
                        } else
                            flag = 1;
                    }
        if (flag == 1)
            printf("NO\n");
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

I got the following error. Please help me.

```
solution.cc: In function 'int main()':
solution.cc:10:19: warning: ignoring return value of 'int scanf(const char*, ...)', 
                   declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
               scanf("%d",&n);
               ^
solution.cc:13:25: warning: ignoring return value of 'int scanf(const char*, ...)',
                   declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
               scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
               ^
```

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. And they are pretty much self explanatory. you are not checking the return values of `scanf()`, thus if there is an error, your program won't be handling it.

Comment: checking the return values as in what? Sorry if my question sounds dumb. i am a beginner.

Comment: Every system call has return values. Just as any function. They have specific meanings. Like `n = printf("hello");`, after this statement executes, `n` wil contain the value `5`. Because `printf()` returns the number of characters printed. Hope you get the hint from this.

Comment: Your code is pure C code, do not use a C++ compiler and `cc` file extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not enter numbers when `scanf` expects them, it will return a number of successful conversions less then what you expect.  It is not a syntax error to ignore this return value, but it is very sloppy as your program will behave in undefined ways if not enough numbers are input.

Fix the code this way:

```
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
    printf("expected number\n");
    return 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &r1, &r2, &c1, &c2, &d1, &d2) != 6) {
        printf("missing numbers\n");
        return 1;
    }
    ...
```

Furthermore, the rest of the code does not seem to have any connection to the lucky number problem.